# Make CarrierWave to not copy original file for versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

As I understand it for each `version` defined in an uploader CarrierWave will copy original file from cache to tmp path and hand over this tmp file to whatever processing is defined for this version. Then it can store all files. Sometimes (e.g. when generating thumbnail for videofile) this copying can be prohibitively expensive. Can I make CarrierWave to not copy and to let me generate versions from the original file while it's in cache?

**Edit** I have `move_to_cache` and `move_to_store` to return <strike>false</strike> true (oops I forget my own head soon). And I wrote a test processing module on the lines of `CarrierWave::RMagick`:

```
module CarrierWave
  module Thumbnailer
    def generate_thumbnails
      debugger
      x = 1
    end
  end
end
```

and I have the following lines inside the uploader

```
version :thumb do
  process :generate_thumbnails
end
```

But when execution is stopped on the `debugger` (that's where I can start processing) CarrierWave has already copied and renamed the uploaded file. I can see both of them inside the cache directory.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the readme under [Large Files](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) ... from the README:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def move_to_cache
    true
  end
  def move_to_store
    true
  end
end
```

> When the move_to_cache and/or move_to_store methods return true, files
>   will be moved (instead of copied) to the cache and store respectively.

Comment: I have that set to false. But that affects how the uploaded file is handled from webserver to CarrierWave cache and to store. It has nothing to do with versions. Right?

Comment: I should probably write custom processing module along the lines of "lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb"

Comment: move_to_cache and move_to_store return true, I did as suggested in Readme, made error while posting here. Sorry